# Is it possible to sort posts by vote using the GD Star Rating plugin?

Tags: plugin-gd-star-rating

Anyone has experience using the [GD Star Rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating) plugin?

and make a loop that sorts posts by vote/stars?

Comment: That wont work because your pagination gets messed up. You cant turn page and you will be able to see only the posts of the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First 2 results on googling for "gd star rating sort posts by rating' are:

- [How to Sort Post by Gd Star Rating](http://www.pramudita.com/how-to-sort-post-by-gd-star-rating.html) <sup>[Mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20121023162132/http://www.pramudita.com/how-to-sort-post-by-gd-star-rating.html)</sup>
- [How to reorder posts](http://www.gdstarrating.com/2009/07/03/how-to-reorder-posts/) <sup>[Mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622161415/http://www.gdstarrating.com/2009/07/03/how-to-reorder-posts)</sup>

> Few examples:
>
> ```
> query_posts("gdsr_sort=rating");
> query_posts("gdsr_sort=review&sort_order=asc");
> query_posts("gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_multi=3");
> query_posts("gdsr_sort=votes&sort_order=asc&gdsr_multi=3");
> ```